# Does Google Maps contain underpass clearance data?

Tags: google-maps

Does Google Maps contain data on underpass clearances?  If yes:

- what's the format & API?
- is it accessible through the standard app?
- where does the data come from?  (do highway depts provide clearance data, and if so, in what format?)
- where is any of this documented?

Comment: what is " data on underpass clearances" ?

Comment: I do not think so but try this site. http://www.lowclearances.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API currently does not have this feature.

Based on your question I have found a relevant feature request from [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820396) which requests truck routing related data like vertical height clearance.

On comment #47 of the link provided it states:

> Unfortunately, Google Maps and the Maps APIs are not targeted at large
>   vehicles.  Data about relevant restrictions comes at a high cost and
>   there are no plans to collect this.  Therefore, truck routing is not
>   on the roadmap and is unlikely to be added in the future.